# How can I add a column and populate it with a number after sorting a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase]
(
    [PhraseId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PhraseNum] [int] NULL
    [English] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

What I would like to do is to sort the table and populate the column `PhraseNum` with a number where the first row of the sorted table is `1` and each row after that has a value one larger than the one before.

Comment: The code looks like SQL Server code so I changed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alan, if data in PhraseNum is not important (as I could see in your post), you can drop that column and add as an identity column

```
ALTER TABLE Phrase drop column PhraseNum ;
ALTER TABLE Phrase Add PhraseNum int identity(1,1) not null;
```

The numbering of PhraseNum will be done by the cluster index sorting criteria, so by PhraseId

But it is safe to test on a test database first

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you would do this with an identity column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase](
    [PhraseId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [PhraseNum] int identity(1, 1) NOT NULL
    [English] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL
);
```

Having a unique identify as a (clustered) primary key is a really, really bad idea.  Why?  New values are not ordered.  That means that the data has to be re-ordered for each `insert` -- causing fragmentation.

You should use the `PhraseNum` column as the primary key.